# Combining IF ELSE clause with UPDATE in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

Trying to combine an UPDATE clause for rows in a table if different conditions are met. I'm doing this via TSQL on Azure SQL.

I could run multiple TSQL statements in the format of the green-ed code that are mutually exclusive from each other, but I'd rather use a nested IF ELSE statement in order to make the code cleaner.

Is this possible?
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, rather than as images.

Comment: Why do think you need a `while` loop?

Comment: Saw it from a previous post but that was to optimize the query on large data sets. Removing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it all in one hit with a `case` expression.

```
update student set
    p2 = case when total_score > 500 then 'pass' else 'fail' end
where p2 is null;
```

You could combine both updates as follows by using a `case` expression to test whether or not the column needs an update:

```
update student set
    p1 = case when p1 is null and age > 20 then 'old' else p1 end
    , p2 = case when p2 is null then case when total_score > 500 then 'pass' else 'fail' end else p2 end
where p2 is null or p1 is null;
```

Note: As a design issue, setting a column value based on the age of a student isn't usually a good idea, because its only giving you a point in time, so you usually then need to keep updating it. Far better to calculate it when you query the table.

Comment: You should rewrite his first query (p1) like that also.

Comment: +10  important point made in this answer about storing `age`;  typically `age` is calculated between two points in time...  for a person, typically the difference between date of birth and now.  and date of birth for a person typically doesn't change, where the difference between dob and now will vary as the value of now varies.   TAKEAWAY:   store `dob` rather than `age`, calculate age when its needed

Comment: Sweet thanks. Pretty new to TSQL so appreciate the pointers.